# Finding the residuals in fitdistrplus package in R

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

I have code where I use fitdistrplus to fit a Weibull distribution to various data sets and plot the raw data to the CDF.

```
##Performs Weibull fit using the Maximum GOF Estimations
 zFIT<-fitdist(x,"weibull",keepdata = TRUE, method = "mge", gof ="KS") ##Changedfrom CvM
 zbFIT <- bootdist(zFIT, niter= 251) 
  zparam<- c(coef(zFIT))
    z_alpha <-zparam[2]
    z_beta <-zparam[1]

 ##Write data output to file
    zDat<-c(summary(zFIT))
    zDataList <-as.vector(zDat[10])
    weibull_Data <-lapply(z, write, "Weibull_Data.txt", append = TRUE)
    weibull_Data <-lapply(zDataList, write, "Weibull_Data.txt", append = TRUE)

 ##Write the parameters to a txt file...
    weibull_params <-lapply(z, write, "Weibull_Fits.txt", append = TRUE)
    weibull_params <-lapply(zparam, write, "Weibull_Fits.txt", append = TRUE)
```

I want to access the residuals of the fit from this calculation to apply a +/- 5 pseudo-sigma screen to identify and count the number of outliers, as these would be considered as an extrinsic defect population.

How do I get a vector, list, or matrix of the residuals.  fitdistr uses the resid() function, fitdistrplus should inherit this function, but it does not seem to work by calling resid(zFIT) ( where zFIT is my fitdist object.....)

Any ideas?  Many thanks

Comment: can you show a reproducible example of `MASS::fitdistr` (assuming that's the alternative function you're referring to) working?  I can't find a `resid` method that works with the results of `MASS::fitdistr` (class `fitdistr`).  I can imagine some methods for computing a p-value or likelihood for a value given a distribution, but I'd like some clarification